# SUM of all values over a certain amount

Tags: sql-server

The question is: Create a script that will calculate and print the total sum of all purchases.

- For all products that
  cost R2000 or more, it must display the phrase ‘SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCTS:’ and the total
  value
- If no products that cost R2000 or more exist, then for all products that cost R1000 or more
  it must display the phrase ‘SUM OF AVERAGE PRODUCTS:’ and the total value.
- If no products that
  cost R1000 or more exist, then for all products that cost less than R1000 must display the phrase
  ‘SUM OF CHEAP PRODUCTS:’ and total value.
- If no products exist at all, then it must display the
  phrase ‘NO PRODUCTS EXIST’.

The marking rubric also says that we must use `DECLARE` and `IF` statements in our answers

The output must look like this:

Sample Results:

(2 row(s) affected )

SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCTS: 5998.00

This is a for a school assignment so I don't expect a full answer, just a push in the right direction as I don't know why this won't work.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014

This is what I've got so far:

```
DECLARE @SUM_OF_EXPENSIVE_PRODUCTS int, @SUM_OF_AVERAGE_PRODUCTS int, @SUM_OF_CHEAP_PRODUCTS int

IF ((SELECT Price AS EXPENSIVE_PRODUCT FROM Product WHERE Price > 2000 ) > 0)
    SELECT SUM(EXPENSIVE_PRODUCT) = @SUM_OF_EXPENSIVE_PRODUCTS

ELSE IF ((SELECT Price AS AVERAGE_PRODUCT FROM Product WHERE Price > 1000) > 0)
    SELECT SUM(AVERAGE_PRODUCT) = @SUM_OF_AVERAGE_PRODUCTS

ELSE IF ((SELECT Price AS CHEAP_PRODUCT FROM Product WHERE Price < 1000) > 0)
    SELECT SUM(CHEAP_PRODUCT) = @SUM_OF_CHEAP_PRODUCTS

ELSE 
    SELECT 'NO PRODUCTS EXIST'
```

Comment: You've discovered by now that isn't correct syntax. Start with this: `SELECT Price FROM YourTable`. Then try this: `SELECT Price, CASE WHEN Price BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999.99 THEN 'AVERAGE_PRODUCT' ELSE NULL END FROM YourTable`. Do the three categories have to appear as columns or rows? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the information you asked for, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

**Updated Query**

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultText varchar(100)
    DECLARE @Result varchar(10)
    IF EXISTS(Select 1 from tempTable WHERE Price > 1999)
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultText = 'SUM_OF_EXPENSIVE_PRODUCTS : '
        SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(Price) from tempTable where Price > 1999)
        SET @ResultText = @ResultText + @Result
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(Select 1 from tempTable WHERE Price > 999)
    BEGIN 
        SET @ResultText = 'SUM_OF_AVERAGE_PRODUCTS : '
        SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(Price) from tempTable where Price > 999)
        SET @ResultText = @ResultText + @Result
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(Select 1 from tempTable WHERE Price > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultText = 'SUM_OF_AVERAGE_PRODUCTS : '
        SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(Price) from tempTable where Price > 0)
        SET @ResultText = @ResultText + @Result
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ResultText = 'NO PRODUCTS EXIST'       
    END
    SELECT @ResultText
END
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, the only problem is that the marking rubric says we have to use a DECLARE statement in the answer

Comment: @ScottyDooZA I don't get what you are asking about! You mean that, you need to make use of DECLARE STATEMENT in the query?

Comment: Yes, the query has to contain a DECLARE statement

Comment: Add `DECLARE @v_NoProducts VARCHAR(100); SET @v_NoProducts = 'NO PRODUCTS EXIST';` And use that in your final select: `SELECT @v_NoProducts;` to get a declare in there. Alternatively you could also declare your price variables.

Comment: @ScottyDooZA find the updated query. If it helps mark it answer..:)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I completely forgot about SET statements